# go two screen back with single press event using react-navigation in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using reactnavigation component from https://reactnavigation.org and using the code below i am going one screen back

```
<Button
          onPress={() => goBack()}
          title="Go back from this HomeScreen"
        />
```

how can i go 2 screen back on single press action

I am using this code to initialize the navigator

```
const RouteConfigs = {
    Login: {screen:Login},
    Home: {screen:Home},
    Chat: {screen:Chat},
    Facebook: {screen:Facebook},
    Facebookgallery: {screen:Facebookgallery}    
}

const StackNavigatorConfig = {
    headerMode: 'none',
}

export default StackNavigator(RouteConfigs, StackNavigatorConfig)
```

I navigate from home to Facebook with this code :

```
() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Facebook', {user:this.state.user})
```

and from Facebook to Facebookgallery with this code :

```
onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Facebookgallery', {user:this.state.user}) }
```

now i want to go back from Facebookgallery to Home directly with some parameters

Answer (score 46):

I know it's an older question but what I use is:

```
navigation.pop(n);
```

Takes you to the previous screen in the stack. If you provide a number, n, it will specify how many screens to take you back within the stack.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html

Comment: Thanks. best answer

Answer (score 14):

you can use `navigation.pop(screenCount)`
with screenCount as integer

```
navigation.pop(2)
```

here is for refference

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions#pop

Answer (score 11):

React Navigation is updated not to use `pop` function directly, use `dispatch` function with `StackActions`.

`navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(2));`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: It's not a special answer, just updated with Khadam Ikhwanus' answer as you know if you see the all the answer of this thread ;)
Because React Navigation is recently updated not to use 'pop' function directly, but use 'dispatch' function with StackActions.

Answer (score 2):

```
navigation.navigate({ routeName: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_A });
navigation.navigate({ routeName: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_B });
navigation.navigate({ routeName: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_C });
navigation.navigate({ routeName: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_D });
```

Now you are on-screen D and want to go back to screen A (popping D, C, and B). Then you need to supply a key to goBack FROM:

navigation.goBack(SCREEN_KEY_B)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#going-back-from-a-specific-screen-with-goback

Answer (score 1):

You could define an additional navigation action type, e.g. `POP_TWO_ROUTES` and overwrite `StackRouter.getStateForAction(passedAction, state)` like that (only exemplary):

```js
    ...
    const defaultGetStateForAction = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

    AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (passedAction, state) => {
      if(state && state.routes && state.routes.length > 2
          && passedAction.type === 'POP_TWO_ROUTES') {
        let routes = state.routes.slice();
        routes.pop();
        routes.pop();

        return {
          index: routes.length - 1,
          routes: routes
        };
      }
      // default behaviour for none custom types
      return defaultGetStateForAction(passedAction, state);
    }
    ...
```

Then in your screen component you can do something like that:

```js
    ...
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch({
      type: 'POP_TWO_ROUTES' 
    })}
    ...
```

See also https://reactnavigation.org/docs/routers/#Custom-Navigation-Actions.

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" solution right now is:

1. Get the key for the screen after the screen you want to go to. In
   your case, you'll need to get the key for the Facebook screen.
2. Call NavigationAction.back(key: 'key-of-previous-screen'), and it
   will pop your navigation stack as if you were on the screen with that key

Code example where I go back multiple screens in a thunk (relevant if you use redux):

```
export const postItemAndReturnToMap = item => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const {nav} = getState();

  // Get the key for the screen after/above the root view and use that as reference
  // to return to the root view. This is hardcoded for my stack setup, as you can see
  // there are quite a few nested StackNavigators in my setup
  const {key} = nav.routes[0].routes[0].routes[0].routes[1];

  // Dispatch whatever action you want
  dispatch(postItem(item));

  // This will now go back multiple screens, in my case to the
  // bottom of the top stackNavigator
  return dispatch(NavigationActions.back({key}));
};
```

This isn't pretty. Let's hope react-navigation implements something like `.back(2)` to make things easier in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `push` then you can go to root screen with this

```
this.props.navigation.popToTop();

and to Push

this.props.navigation.navigate('SummaryScreen', {
    otherParam: 'anything you want here',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something along the lines of #reset (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset).

I haven't used this library, but you likely are trying to go back to the navigation stack's root screen.  Other libraries I've used for nav have some sort of `popToRoot` or something similar.

Comment: no i cannot use this because in root i am using scroller and i need to go back to same scroller screen from where the navigation is originating. it works when do  onPress={() => goBack()} 2 times on the two different screens but i need it go directly to 2 screen back as its happening when manually pressing back button

Comment: Reset wipes the entire stack and resets (recreates) all views that would reside underneath. This may work if the view you want to reset to is light and loads quickly, but if not, it doesn't provide a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onPress={() => {
    props.rootNavigation.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key:null,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })]
      })
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
this.props.navigation.pop(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For React Native V6 2022

Simple Go Back "goBack"

```
navigation.goBack()
```

Go Back tow screen or 3 on specific the name "navigate"

```
props.navigation.navigate("RouteName")
```

Navigate to the top screen "popToTop"

```
navigation.popToTop()
```